# Windows 8.1 not appearing on grub after Linux Mint 16

Tags: linux, boot, windows

I had followed a tutorial to install Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon and it works perfectly fine, currently using it to post this question. But when grub loads the only 3 options I am given, are Linux Mint, Linux Mint (Compatibility Mode) and system startup. My computer has come pre-installed with windows 8 on it, both the recovery and windows partition are still visible on the disk usage analyzer. When I installed Linux I had legacy mode turned on but if I turn it off, Linux still works fine.

I've tried the "sudo update-grub" command and it reads as follows

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
  No volume groups found
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

I would still like to dual boot Linux alongside Windows, what do I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: Open a terminal and run `sudo fdisk -l`. This will tell us where's Windows installed.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider manually modifying grub.cfg, editing /etc/grub.d/40_custom

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB2#Dual-booting

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.